# I want to initialize App.init() after onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, initialization, components

I am trying to integrate a mortage calculator on my wordpress site. I have 2 main problem:

1. I want to integrate multiple calculator on one page individually, so I created html components:

```js
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnclick(this)" data-attr="refinance" data-toggle-dlc="modal" data-target="#dlc_calculator_modal" data-view="refinance"></button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//secure.dominionlending.ca/calculators/js/embed.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> DLCCALCULATOR.init({ header: { type: 1 }, calculator: [1], button: { type: 3, btnText: "", aId: "", aClass: "" } });</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> DLCCALCULATOR.init({ header: { type: 1 }, calculator: [2], button: { type: 3, btnText: "", aId: "", aClass: "" } });</script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://faizalgarasia.com/wp-content/themes/DLCContemporary/img/widgetImages/Mortgage_Payment.svg">
    </div>
<div class="col-md">
<h2>Mortgage Payment</h2>
</div>
</div>

<p>Shave years off your Mortgage and save you thousands by using an accelerated bi-weekly mortgage payment.</p>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mortgagecalculator" id="mortgagecalculator" aId="mortgagecalculator" aClass="mortgagecalculator" data-toggle-dlc="modal" data-target="#dlc_calculator_modal" data-view="mortgagecalculator">Use Now</a>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <img src="http://faizalgarasia.com/wp-content/themes/DLCContemporary/img/widgetImages/Refinance_Renewal.svg">
    </div>
<div class="col-md">
<h2>Refinance or Renewal Calculator</h2>
</div>
</div>

<p>Gives you quick access to loan options and the difference they can make in your monthly mortgage payment.</p>

<a href="#" aClass: "refinance" aId="refinance" class="btn btn-primary refinance" id="refinance" data-toggle-dlc="modal" data-target="#dlc_calculator_modal" data-view="refinance">Use Now</a>
```

But Whenever I put the scripts I get only one calculator. so I derived on the second solution which is:

2. I created if else statement like this:

```js
<script src="text\javascrtipt">
function mortagecalculator(btn)
{
  if (btn.mortagecalculator == "mortage") 
  {
      <script type="text/javascript"> DLCCALCULATOR.init({                calculator: [1], button: { type: 3, btnText: "Use Now", aId:        "", aClass: "" } });</script>
  }
  else if (btn.mortagecalculator == "penalty")
  {
    <script type="text/javascript"> DLCCALCULATOR.init({                calculator: [2], button: { type: 3, btnText: "Use Now", aId:        "", aClass: "" } });</script>
  }
}

</script>
```

```html
<--created two buttons-->

<a onlick="mortagecalculator" data-attr="mortage">Use Now</a>

<a onlick="mortagecalculator" data-attr="penalty">Use Now</a>
```

Output: it will redirect me into a blankpage.

Comment: In your 2nd example, you are nesting script tags. Not allowed but not necessary anyway. Remove the inner script tags.

Comment: You sure this is not a typo? `<a onlick="mortagecalculator" data-attr="penalty">Use Now</a>`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava. where's typo on there? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Here - `onlick`

Comment: @ChrisG I already updated my code on the second one, it still redirected me into a blank page

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I already edit it. and put a console.log but then I got same problem. it will redirected me to a blank page.